# *.tif file from GDAL not loading in QGIS 3.22.11 in Citrix workspace

Tags: qgis, gdal, qgis-3, geotiff-tiff, citrix

I have an ESA land change map 2015 in .tif format which works fine on my desktop QGIS setup
(v 3.22.6) but gives the following error when uploading the same file to the Citrix Workspace environment:

> ESACCI-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P1Y-2015-v2.0.7.tif: TIFFReadDirectory:Failed to read directory at offset 311696358

I have checked all plugins, there are no relevant differences between them. I tried converting to .map and saving as QGIS project file, which made no difference for the file format.

When clicking on the warning icon of the culprit layer, it asks to repair the data source with a different layer, which I do not have. Is there something I am missing?